# Printing out a 8 bit register as two hex characters with NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am attempting to print out the hex value of an 8 bit register in assembly for a bootloader. I have written code to print out values, but only as ASCII characters. For example:

```
BITS 16

start:
    mov ax, 07C0h
    add ax, 288
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 4096

    mov ax, 02h
    int 10h
    mov ax, 07C0h
    mov ds, ax

    mov al, 19h
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h

    jmp $

    ret
    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

When i compile this with NASM, it prints out an ASCII symbol. I want it to be able to print out "19", how would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Take the high nibble (i.e. `(al AND 0F0h) LSR 4`), add `30h` (`'0'`) to it. If the result is greater than `39h` (`'9'`), add 7. Then print that, and repeat the same steps for the low nibble (`al AND 0Fh`).

Comment: You don't really need the `AND 0F0h`, since the shift will clear the low bits anyway.